# vCard extensions on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, vcf-vcard

I want to know if vCard in BlackBerry supports private extensions, such as X-ANNIVERSARY and X-ASSISTANT.   If so, how are these extensions handled when the vcard containing these fields are transfered to other non RIM devices?

Answer (score 1):

Thorough testing reveals blackberry only supports v2.1 of the vcard standard